# Bernoulli differential equation $y'(x)+2y=\frac{x}{y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck solving this Bernoulli differential equation because I can't get it in the proper form:

> $y'(x)+2y=\frac{x}{y^2}$
>
> Proper form: $y'+p(x)\;y=q(x)\;y^n$

I was able to get it into the following form:

$y^2y'(x)+2y^3=x$

Which means:

$v=y^3$

$v'=3y^2y'\Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}v'+2v=x$

$e^{\int2v\;dv}=e^{v^2}$

At this point I didn't notice that there was no function of $x$ in my second term.  Am I going about this the correct way or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Using the suggestions in the comments and continuing on:

$\frac{dv}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{v^2}}{3}+2ve^{v^2}=xe^{v^2}\right)\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{3}+2v\right)=x$

And separating gives:

$\left(\frac{1}{3}+2v\right)dv=xdx$

After integrating both of these equations I get:

$\frac{1}{3}v+v^2=x^2+c$

Comment: What you've done is correct. In this case, $p(x)=1$.

Comment: @Moo I kept going... how does this look?  The final equation doesn't seem right

Comment: @Moo I divided through, but clearly I must have done something wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in this equation :

[image]

But this leads to nothing.

The first order non-homogeneous linear ODE :  $v'+6v=3x$ can be solved thanks to the usual method :

First, solve the homogeneous ODE $v'+6v=0$ which is separable : $\frac{dv}{v}=-6dx\quad\to\quad v=C\:e^{-6x}$

Second, substitute an unknown function $f(x)$ to the constant $C$ and put it into the non-homogeneous ODE :

$v=f(x)e^{-6x}\quad\to\quad \left(f(x)e^{-6x}\right)'+6f(x)e^{-6x}=3x \quad\to\quad f'(x)e^{-6x}=3x\quad\to\quad f(x)=\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{12}\right)e^{-6x}+c$

$$v=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{12}+c\:e^{-6x}$$